# Quickly assert the non-presence of an element without waiting in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The Java Junit exporter in Selenium IDE sets a 30 second [implicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits) by default. This means, the assertion to test an element does not exist will result in an unnecessary delay for 30 seconds.

I have tried using explicit wait (`WebDriverWait` class) with a timeout of 1, but it still took around 30 sec.

So is there anyway to bypass implicit wait for all kinds of locators (i.e. `By` classes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(by);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return false;
    }
}
```

disgusting but works. Seems like every command which implicitly waits should be able to be overloaded. but find element doesn't have a 2 param version. Maybe it's in By?

Answer (score 2):

Unset implicit waits if you use explicit ones:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```